# Request to merge tags [azure-hdinsight] and [hdinsight]

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I have spotted two separate tags related to Azure HDInsight service:

[azure-hdinsight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-hdinsight) and [hdinsight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hdinsight)

Both the tags should be merged into one as [azure-hdinsight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-hdinsight).

We are looking to align Stack Overflow tags to match with Azure Services and Microsoft Q&A platform.

Azure HDInsight has [azure-hdinsight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-hdinsight) tag in Microsoft Q&A.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/topics/azure-hdinsight.html

---

**Update:** I'm able to merge by using Tag synonyms.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This is quite sensible, and I'm happy to perform the merge. While we don't necessarily share your specific goals of making Stack Overflow match Microsoft Q&A, there is an established pattern of using the `[azure-*]` naming convention in tags related to technologies under the Azure umbrella.

**However**, I reviewed the questions tagged [hdinsight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hdinsight), and of those, there were several that I couldn't discern whether or not they were about Azure HDInsight:

- [Map Reduce program to merge multiple xml files to a single xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34884505/map-reduce-program-to-merge-multiple-xml-files-to-a-single-xml-file)
- [How to get appropriate size of input split in mapreduce job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35590019/how-to-get-appropriate-size-of-input-split-in-mapreduce-job)
- [Can we use PostgreSQL with PolyBase To connect Hadoop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38450431/can-we-use-postgresql-with-polybase-to-connect-hadoop)
- [What's difference between HDInsight Hadoop cluster & HDInsight Spark cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340418/whats-difference-between-hdinsight-hadoop-cluster-hdinsight-spark-cluster)
- [How do you recover dead node in HDInsight Hadoop (Linux) cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38493282/how-do-you-recover-dead-node-in-hdinsight-hadoop-linux-cluster)
- [YARN Summary for newly created HDInsight cluster shows 6 completed applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38643810/yarn-summary-for-newly-created-hdinsight-cluster-shows-6-completed-applications)
- [listing submitted jobs in HDInsight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25016649/listing-submitted-jobs-in-hdinsight)
- [How do I install Custom Jar in HDInsight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32008316/how-do-i-install-custom-jar-in-hdinsight)
- [Create external table with select from other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30537584/create-external-table-with-select-from-other-table)
- [Losing decimal places in hive tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30580244/losing-decimal-places-in-hive-tables)
- [Hadoop HDInsight .NET SDK APIs to submit job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533672/hadoop-hdinsight-net-sdk-apis-to-submit-job)
- [Does order of partitioning columns matter in Hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58268082/does-order-of-partitioning-columns-matter-in-hive)
- [Connection refused error while submitting spark job on HDInsight spark cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43755010/connection-refused-error-while-submitting-spark-job-on-hdinsight-spark-cluster)
- [Listing clusters using MVC (the page keeps loading for hours)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27882838/listing-clusters-using-mvc-the-page-keeps-loading-for-hours)
- [FAILED: RuntimeException Hive internal error: conversion of string to void not supported yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32662044/failed-runtimeexception-hive-internal-error-conversion-of-string-to-void-not-s)
- [Sourcing data from DocumentDB in Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34443999/sourcing-data-from-documentdb-in-hadoop)
- [HDInsight Hive UDF in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22706736/hdinsight-hive-udf-in-net)
- [save hive or hbase table in hdinsight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43966695/save-hive-or-hbase-table-in-hdinsight)
- ["Not a file" exception on select after successful insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30580097/not-a-file-exception-on-select-after-successful-insert)
- [ARM Deployment failed due to dependOn in EdgeNode on HDI cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43678040/arm-deployment-failed-due-to-dependon-in-edgenode-on-hdi-cluster)
- [writing data to filesystem from hive queries in hdinsight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40341169/writing-data-to-filesystem-from-hive-queries-in-hdinsight)
- [i want read a source file and write data into .Csv file in Spark scala with additional identity columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45230526/i-want-read-a-source-file-and-write-data-into-csv-file-in-spark-scala-with-addi)
- [HDInsight - Cluster is not responding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698639/hdinsight-cluster-is-not-responding)
- [Getting SemanticException on a very simple query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39739631/getting-semanticexception-on-a-very-simple-query)
- [How to change the mapper/reduce memory in HDInsight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31661957/how-to-change-the-mapper-reduce-memory-in-hdinsight)
- [HIVE table create and select success, but next query says table does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30493770/hive-table-create-and-select-success-but-next-query-says-table-does-not-exist)
- [HDInsight - use more than 1 storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846728/hdinsight-use-more-than-1-storage)
- [Insert Overwrite: Cannot move ... to the trash, as it contains the trash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30577083/insert-overwrite-cannot-move-to-the-trash-as-it-contains-the-trash)
- [How to see my application's exception in hdinsight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27120067/how-to-see-my-applications-exception-in-hdinsight)
- [How to view log in Spark in HDInsight after app exit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29245070/how-to-view-log-in-spark-in-hdinsight-after-app-exit)
- [Unable to delete HDInsight cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40504219/unable-to-delete-hdinsight-cluster)
- [Hive Update 0.14 version is not working Attempt to do update or delete using transaction manager that does not support these operations.“](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33928281/hive-update-0-14-version-is-not-working-attempt-to-do-update-or-delete-using-tra)
- [HDInsight HBase, configure hbase using blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176013/hdinsight-hbase-configure-hbase-using-blob)
- [How to handle HDInsight Hbase Major compactions? Hbase is not reachable when the major compaction take place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37322127/how-to-handle-hdinsight-hbase-major-compactions-hbase-is-not-reachable-when-the)
- [Passing parameters to Pig script with HDInsight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16169616/passing-parameters-to-pig-script-with-hdinsight)
- [Hadoop / HDInsight for replacing SANs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339678/hadoop-hdinsight-for-replacing-sans)

…and that's just the first page of results.

It looks like there may be some other sort of Hadoop or Hive technology that is called HDInsight. Is that the same as Azure HDInsight? Did Microsoft buy this up and/or incorporate it into Azure?

Even if they did, is there a need to retain separate tagging/versioning for the old, pre-Microsoft stuff?

**I need someone with subject-matter expertise to provide some clarity here before I can do the merge/rename.**

Comment: FYI, I'm working on Azure HDInsight from past five years. The questions listed above are related to Azure HDInsight. Both the tags has the questions related to Azure HDInsight. I would suggest you to merge both the tags with the name called "azure-hdinsight".

Comment: Both the tags are merged by using tag synonyms option available on SO.